# Rendering a different Kohana template at the action level

Tags: php, kohana

I have an account controller with a template called 'account'. I'm just trying to figure out how to specify a different template for my login / forgot password actions.

Comment: Any code we can have thoughts about? I can't tell if you are using the Controller_Template or a Mustache view or whatever from that one sentence.

Comment: Nice question. Why was it downvoted? I had been having the same problem and the @david-winter's answer has helped me (tested in Kohana 3.3.1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your controller is extended `Controller_Template`? In the controllers `before` method, you could check the name of the action and change the template based on that:

```
<?php

class Controller_Account extends Controller_Template {

    // This is the default template used for all actions
    public $template = 'account';

    public function before()
    {
        // You can add actions to this array that will then use a different template
        if (in_array($this->request->action(), array('login', 'forgot_password')))
        {
            $this->template = 'diff_template';
        }

        parent::before();
    }
```

Comment: I have just tested this in Kohana 3.3.1. Works grest. Thanks. Upvoted.